# Parameterized Update not updating a NULL default DateTime

Tags: c#, mysql

I have the following code:

```
string sql = "UPDATE csar.UsersLog SET LoggedOffAt=@LoggedOffAt WHERE UserId=@UId AND LoggedOffAt=@Null;";

        try
        {

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uid", USERID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoggedOffAt", DateTime.UtcNow);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Null", null);

            int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (rows == 1)
                return true;
            else
            {
                LastKnownError = "Failed to Insert Link";
                return false;
            }

        }
        catch (MySqlException mye)
        {
            LastKnownError = mye.Message;
            return false;
        }
```

Unfortunately it does not work. It is supposed to update the logged on and logged off table CSAR.UsersLog with the current DateTime. However, even though the UId is correct and the LoggedOffAt DateTime Column is defaulted to NULL the record is not updated.

Any help?

Comment: `@uid` != `@UId`... and you have no errors? Also you sure the connection is open?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ No I said, the UId is correct. There are no errors and yes of course the connection is open.

Comment: the param names don't match, didn't say the value was wrong :)

Comment: `SET LoggedOffAt=@LoggedOffAt WHERE UserId=@UId AND LoggedOffAt=@Null` will more than likely never be true. Try `SET LoggedOffAt=@LoggedOffAt WHERE UserId=@UId AND LoggedOffAt IS NULL` and remove that param.

Comment: NULL is equal to nothing, not even NULL. You need the `IS` condition to test for NULL and there is no reason to parameterize that. You want `AND LoggedOffAt IS NULL`.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I never noticed the UId parameter did not match. However, repairing that did not fix the problem.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ if you set the "IS NULL" comment as the answer then you get the points my friend. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unfortunately it does not work. It is supposed to update the logged on and logged off table CSAR.UsersLog with the current DateTime. However, even though the UId is correct and the LoggedOffAt DateTime Column is defaulted to NULL

```
string sql = "UPDATE csar.UsersLog SET LoggedOffAt=@LoggedOffAt WHERE UserId=@UId AND LoggedOffAt=@Null;";

    try
    {

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uid", USERID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoggedOffAt", DateTime.UtcNow);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Null", null);

        int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (rows == 1)
            return true;
        else
        {
            LastKnownError = "Failed to Insert Link";
            return false;
        }

    }
    catch (MySqlException mye)
    {
        LastKnownError = mye.Message;
        return false;
    }
```

The first thing I noticed about the query was your param names didn't match the one's that you were providing, for example:

```
 WHERE UserId=@UId
```

Should have been:

```
 WHERE UserId=@uid
```

Looking closer at the query I did notice you were trying to pass `null` as a value to use in the where clause; you **don't need this parameter** and you can change your `where` clause to handle the `null`. To do that look at [IS NULL/ IS NOT NULL](https://www.guru99.com/null.html) here. **If you wanted to really pass a null value** then that would look something like `DBNull.Value` and **not** null (of which is nothing).

**To fix the problem:**

```
 WHERE UserId=@uid AND LoggedOffAt IS NULL;
```

On another note, look into [using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) statements to ensure disposing of your objects.

Comment: Regarding the last sentence of your answer, there's nothing wrong with using `AddWithValue` for MySQL: https://mysqlconnector.net/overview/using-addwithvalue/

Comment: @BradleyGrainger thanks for that link, I've edited my post.